# How do I call the function to remove the suffix?

Tags: python, methods

I want to pass each word inside the results to the stemm method to remove suffixes. However, on printing my 'final' list, I observe that the method isn't working on the words. Am I calling the function wrongly?

```
             results=[]
             with open('/Users/mnk/Documents/Stemtry.txt') as filer:
                 for line in filer:
                    results.append(line.strip().split())
             result=[]
             final=[]

             def stemm(n):
                 for suffix in ['ing', 'ly', 'ed', 'ious', 'ies', 'ive', 'es', 's', 'ment']:
                    if n.endswith(suffix):
                        return n[:-len(suffix)]
                    return n

             for eachitem in results[:10]:
                 for n in eachitem:
                     r=stemm(n)
                     final.append(r)
             print(final)               
             result.append(final)
```

Comment: `stemm(n)` has an empty body. Indentation is [**`key`** in Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Comment: Indentation is part of Python syntax. Please, make sure your code is correct and code snippets have sane indentation as your local code.

Comment: put `print(n)` in `stemm` to check what words it get. Are you sure that you are checking words, not letters ?

Comment: @furas On inserting a print statement in stemm, I do not receive anything as the output. But when I insert a inline print(r) , it does print out words. So it's confirmed that it is checking for words not letters. However, the function isn't working.

Comment: your `stemm` function has a return statement in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

**De-indent line 12 ("return n") once**. It'll then wait until all of the suffixes have been checked before returning the result. You can also use an `else` clause.

```
def stemm(n):
    for suffix in ['ing', 'ly', 'ed', 'ious', 'ies', 'ive', 'es', 's', 'ment']:
        if n.endswith(suffix):
            return n[:-len(suffix)]
    else:
        return n
```